# Is there any way to query java heap like OQL in debugger and heap analysers, but at runtime

Tags: java

I have the need to select a configurable set of objects that my application generates. These objects are then validated against a set of Rules written in various languages ( Bean validation annotations, MVEL, Groovy for now).

I'd like to provide a simple and generic way to select the objects to be validated. For now it is done with a custom collector that simply register the objects that will be validated with some logic to reject or accept the candidate objects.

I was wondering if there are somme libraries that can be used at runtime to select with an expression like OQL a set of objects.

Reading QueryDSL doc quickly it seems that it cannot generically query the heap.

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't know of a specific way to do this.  And I think it is impossible.  The information you are trying to access is only available via the JVMTI.  My understanding is that an application running in a JVM cannot use JVMTI to access its own JVM.

Comment: So actually what you say implies that it could be implemented as a JVMTI agent.

Comment: No ... because a JVM cannot use JVMTI on itself.

Comment: Ah ok sorry for the misunderstanding